# exclude first value from foreach django

Tags: django, foreach

Hi I have a shopping cart site powered by django 
in this i got a thumbnail images  of product by using below code

```
{% for image in images %}
    <li>
        <a  rel="zoom-id:zoom;" rev="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{% thumbnail image.file 510 700 %}"  class="MagicThumb-swap"  href="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{% thumbnail image.file 2500 3500 %}">
            <img alt="{{ image.description }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{% thumbnail image.file 75 100 %}">
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

which has a multile images

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
```

i need to show the first image or value from the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to show only 1st image from images.

So you can use [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter to cut your list into 1 item and use that, like

```
 {% for image in images|slice:"1" %}

    {# your code #}

 {% endfor %}
```

Or you can use `forloop.first` and have that code, like

```
 {% for image in images %}
    {% if forloop.first %}

        {# your code #}

    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Update:

To exclude first and show remaining

```
 {% for image in images %}
    {% if forloop.first %} {# Do nothing #}
    {% else %}

        {# your code #}

    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: i mean can i exclude a aparticular number and show all other remaining

Comment: this works fine for first but can you please tell ow can i exclude 2 . 3 or 4 th 

 {% for image in images %}
    {% if forloop.first %}

        {# your code #}

    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}

Comment: Use forloop.counter0 to match specific numbers. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for